# How to transfer c++ stringstream binary data to java

Tags: java, c++, binary-data, stringstream

I have a requirement to use boost binary_oarchive to serialize my data and then transfer to my android app.

```
string MyCppClass::GetSerializeData() {
  std::stringstream os;
  {
    ::boost::archive::binary_oarchive oa(os, boost::archive::no_header);
    oa << my_data;
  }
  return os.str();
}
```

I wrote a jni code to transfer c++ string to java string.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL getCppData(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {
  std::string temp = MyCppClass.GetSerializeData();
  jstring orb_string = env->NewStringUTF(temp.c_str());
  return orb_string;
}
```

But this way doesn't work, I've tried to just write a normal string to stringstream like:

```
std::stringstream os;
os << "Test";
return os.str();
```

It works fine. So I think the problem is my c++ string is binary format.
I want to ask how to transfer c++ binary string to java side?

Comment: this sounds bizarre.  if you control both ends, who dictates requirement to use boost serialization?  Consider using protocol buffers or other portable serialization library.

Comment: in your archive code is there even any data in the archive? What's in  my_data ?

Comment: my_data is the data created from c++ code, I need to transfer it to java code, then combine with another data to save as a file. The data is created periodically, I want to save them as a file so I can use the same data to reproduce the bug.